# How to reply emails

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

My partner emailed me this saying that he doesn't meant to be critical about my work wants to make everything perfect so we can get succeed.

"I don't ever mean to be critical - I am just trying to help you to ensure our success!"

I want to reply to him that he is not being critical, in fact I love his ideas to improve my work. I am not able to write a good sentence explaining my feelings.

Please help me what should I reply to him.

Comment: Please add what you are thinking of saying in your response.

Comment: I want to say "You were not critical at all. I am glad that you shared your ideas with me to ensure our success"

Answer (score 1):

Your partner is probably being polite by saying he doesn't mean to be critical.  The best response might be, "Thank you for the feedback, even if it was critical.  I found it helpful and appreciate your truthfulness."